# Removing values from a 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl

```
void Draw() {
int c1;
int x = 59;
int y = 500;
int temp = x;
for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
        x_coordinates[i][j] = x;
        y_coordinates[i][j] = y;

    c1 = temp_color[i][j];
    DrawRectangle(x, y, 65, 25, colors[c1]);
            x += 67;
        }
        x = temp;
        y -= 28;
}
DrawRectangle(tempx, 0, 85, 12, colors[5]);
DrawCircle(templx, temply, 10, colors[7]);
    }
    // This function will be called automatically by this frequency 1000.0 / FPS
    void Animate() {
        //if (temply < - 10)
        //exit(1);
        Brick_collision(  );
        glutPostRedisplay(); // Once again call the Draw member function
    }
    int Brick_collision(){
    for (int i=0; i<13; ++i){
        for (int j=0; j<10; ++j){
            if (((templx >= x_coordinates[i][j]) && (templx <= x_coordinates[i][j] + 65)) && ((temply + 5 >= y_coordinates[i][j]) && (temply + 5 <= y_coordinates[i][j] + 35  ))){
                vy = -vy;

                temp_color[i][j] = 2;
              //  x_coordinates[i][j] -= 300;
               // y_coordinates[i][j] -= 300;
               // I HAVE USED THESE VALUES BECAUSE NOW THE BRICK WOULD BE OUTSIDE THE SCREEN AND THE BALL WILL NOT COLLIDE WITH IT AGAIN BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK.

                return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to make a BrickSlayer game using OpenGL. In the `Draw()` function I am drawing the structure of the game i.e the bricks, pedal and the ball. Now I am storing the x and y co-ordinates of the bricks in a 2-D Array. And In the `Animate()` function I am calling the function `Brick_collision()` In which I have applied the condition for the detection of the bricks. As the ball collides with brick I make it invinssible i.e I change its colour to White and also I have to remove its co-ordinates from the 2-D array so the ball does not detect it again. How can I achive this? All the methods that I have used for the removal of co-ordinates have not worked.

Comment: What do you mean _remove_? You can't remove elements from fixed sized arrays. Did you mean you need to reset these values? Otherwise I'd recommend to use something like a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: By remove I mean could I change the value for the specific brick's 'x' and 'y' co-ordinate in the array.

Comment: FYI: this is *not* a 2D array, it's a jagged array

Answer (score 0):

I think your "Magic Number" solution could work. Just add some logic to your collision detection to look for that magic number specifically and ignore it if it is a match. I.E.:

```
int Brick_collision(){
    for (int i=0; i<13; ++i){
        for (int j=0; j<10; ++j){
            if (((x_coordinates[i][j] != -300) && 
                 (y_coordinates[i][j] != -300) && 
                 (templx >= x_coordinates[i][j]) && 
                 (templx <= x_coordinates[i][j] + 65)) &&
                ((temply + 5 >= y_coordinates[i][j]) && 
                 (temply + 5 <= y_coordinates[i][j] + 35))){

                vy = -vy;

                temp_color[i][j] = 2;

               // x_coordinates[i][j] -= 300;
               // y_coordinates[i][j] -= 300;
               // I HAVE USED THESE VALUES BECAUSE NOW THE BRICK 
               // WOULD BE OUTSIDE THE SCREEN AND THE BALL WILL NOT 
               // COLLIDE WITH IT AGAIN BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK.
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't think you got my question fully. Simply adding this new condition would not change anything. This would just check if the values of the co-ordinate are not equal to -300.

Comment: I was thinking that adding this check ensures that after you set them to -300 during a successful collision. Any subsequent run ins with these coordinates would FAIL the IF block. I maybe misinterpret how this game's logic is working but it seems like some version of a set and check with a magic number should allow you to escape the collision logic.